# ngrx: initial action fired twice for reducers

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

```
//first.reducer.ts
export function firstReducer(state: number = 0, action: actions.actionsForFirst): number{
    console.log("firstReducer")
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type) {
        ...
        return state;
    }        
}

//second.reducer.ts
export function secondReducer(state: string = "qwe", action: actions.actionsForSecond): string {
    console.log("secondReducer")
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type) {
        ...
        return state;
    }        
}

 //store.module.ts
    const reducers = {  firstReducer, secondReducer };
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            StoreModule.provideStore(reducers), //import reducers
        ],
        ...
    })
    export class StoreModule { };

//app.module.ts
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CoreStoreModule } from './core-store.module'; // module with reducers
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        CoreStoreModule,
        effects.map(effect => EffectsModule.run(effect)) //register some imported effects
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Log output:

> firstReducer Object type: "@ngrx/store/init"**proto**: Object
>
> secondReducer Object type: "@ngrx/store/init"**proto**: Object
>
> firstReducer Object type: "@ngrx/store/init"**proto**: Object
>
> secondReducer Object type: "@ngrx/store/init"**proto**: Object

i.e. @ngrx/store/init action was fired twice for both firstReducer and secondReducer.

What can it be the reason of this behavior? There is [the open issue](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/280) for it

Comment: What sort of answer were you hoping to get? The GitHub issue to which you've linked has a [comment from one of the authors](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/280#issuecomment-280651314) that says you "should only provide store in your root AppModule's imports". Putting the store in a feature module is discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/281), too. My understanding is that it is not yet supported.

Answer (score 3):

In store module, you init the store with `StoreModule.provideStore(reducers)`. Then you in main module imported the store module. It make it init twice. you should add `StoreModule.provideStore(reducers)` only in main module.